# Unsolicited Response (+STCR) from SIM Toolkit not visible

Tags: sms, gsm, modem, ussd, sim-toolkit

I'm testing a SIM Toolkit application using AT Commands. I have a USB modem that supports SIM Toolkit Class 2 features and is based on the Open AT Firmware. I am able to successfully interact with the SIM Toolkit by using the +STSF, +STGI, and +STGR commands. I also receive +STIN replies as per the message flow shown [here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/61188000/196/Messages-Exchanged-During-a-SIM-Toolkit-Operation). What I do not receive is the Unsolicited Response (+STCR) from the SIM when an SMS message or USSD message is sent out. I am using the following Terminal Profile during initialization:

```
AT+STSF=2,"5FFFFFFF7F",3,1
```

Based on the Terminal Profile, the Call Control bit is set to 1 or enabled. You will also notice that the Autoresponse is set to 1. Therefore, I receive an +STGI response when a message is sent. Here is the lead up to when the SIM sends an SMS message:

```
AT+STGR=6,1,1
OK

+STIN: 9

+STGI: ""

OK
```

You can see that `+STIN: 9` means an SMS message is sent out. I believe based on my initialization, I should also see an +STCR and there should be some text in the +STGI. If anyone is familiar with the SIM Toolkit and accessing it through the AT Command set, then I would appreciate some insight as to why I do not receive a response when an SMS message is sent out. Thanks.

Reference: 
1: Wavecom AT Commands Interface Guide for X51a - WM_ASW_OAT_UGD_00016

Comment: Whats your modem ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the USB modem is busy for doing other task.

If you send response with `0x91xx` instead of `0x9000` again and again while you don't receive Instruction byte ie `0x12` ie `FETCH` command.

where `XX` means no of STK byte .